# Alignment of JPanels

Tags: java, swing

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm at a complete loss. I'm trying to create a simple program that draws a circle and outputs it's properties on the screen. Functionally, the program works fine, but the layout of the JPanels is off. For some reason, there is a gap between the JPanel that holds the 'Draw Me' button and the JPanel that holds the circle. Even if I resize the height of the program, the gap doesn't disappear. Likewise, the labels within the program aren't aligning to the left, they kind of sit off-center for some weird reason, removing the border doesn't seem to help. I'm stuck...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
private JPanel userHelpSubPanel;
private JPanel inputSubPanel;
private JPanel buttonSubPanel;
private JPanel drawSubPanel;
private JPanel resultsSubPanel;
private JLabel userHelpLabel;
private JLabel diameterLabel;
private JLabel circumferenceLabel;
private JLabel areaLabel;
private JButton drawButton;
private JTextField inputTextField;
private float radius;

public MainPanel() {
    radius = 0;

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    userHelpSubPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    inputSubPanel = new JPanel();
    inputSubPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputSubPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    drawSubPanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(150, 20, radius * 2, radius * 2));
        }
    };

    resultsSubPanel = new JPanel();
    resultsSubPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(resultsSubPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    buttonSubPanel = new JPanel();

    userHelpLabel = new JLabel();
    userHelpLabel.setText("Enter the radius of the ellipse: ");

    inputTextField = new JTextField();
    inputTextField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, inputTextField.getPreferredSize().height));

    drawButton = new JButton("Draw Me");
    drawButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MainPanel.this.radius = Float.parseFloat(inputTextField.getText());

            diameterLabel.setText(String.format("Diameter: %.1f", 2 * radius));
            circumferenceLabel.setText(String.format("Circumference: %.1f", 2 * Math.PI * radius));
            areaLabel.setText(String.format("Area: %.1f", Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2)));

            drawSubPanel.repaint();
        }
    });

    circumferenceLabel = new JLabel("Circumference: N/A");
    diameterLabel = new JLabel("Diameter: N/A");
    areaLabel = new JLabel("Area: N/A");

    userHelpSubPanel.add(userHelpLabel);
    inputSubPanel.add(inputTextField);
    buttonSubPanel.add(drawButton);
    resultsSubPanel.add(diameterLabel);
    resultsSubPanel.add(circumferenceLabel);
    resultsSubPanel.add(areaLabel);

    add(userHelpLabel);
    add(inputSubPanel);
    add(buttonSubPanel);
    add(drawSubPanel);
    add(resultsSubPanel);
}
}
```

And here is what it looks like....

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEHVE.png]

Comment: Use GridBagLayout - it's best for the task you have. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Answer (score 1):

BoxLayout will respect the minimum and maximum sizes of a component. So if there is extra space in the frame then the panels will be given more space.

The solution is to override the `getMaximumSize()` method of the custom panel to return the preferred size of the panel.

Every Swing component is responsibile for determiningin its own preferred size. So this would mean you also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` of the panel where you do the custom painting. The preferred size would be based on the size/location of the oval that you are drawing.

Answer (score -3):

A simple fix for these issues is to give your panels (relevant ones) an empty border and then reduce the specific direction that is too large:

```
// this example reduces the top of your circle panel.
drawSubPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(-100, 0, 0, 0));
```

Obviously this isn't the root of the problem and isn't the most optimal but it should do the trick.

Comment: (1-) This is not the solution. The size of the panel changes dynamically as the frame is resized. Hardcoding any value in a EmptyBorder is simply not the way to solve the problem. Use Swing the way it was designed to be used.

Comment: Can you read? Clearly not. You are wrong on so many levels. Maybe get off your chair and give him an answer then know-it-all? Funny you plan to spend less time then me on this question and yet you sit back and criticize as if you completely missed my disclaimer.